# how to get a user's location in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, geolocation, location, flutter-getx

I want to locate the user and send his location coordinates via api to the server, Please answer with code, I've tried library geolocator: ^7.7.0

```
void getCurrentLocation() async {
     Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
     var lat = position.latitude;
     var long = position.longitude;
 print("Latitude: $lat and Longitude: $long");
   }
```

This code is not working , Error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getCurrentPosition on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)
E/flutter (25476): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156
E/flutter (25476): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25476): #1      MethodChannelGeolocator.getCurrentPosition (package:geolocator_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:128:27)
E/flutter (25476): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25476): #2      getCurrentLocation
package:check_time/Screens/fingerprint_Screen.dart:84
E/flutter (25476): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: run flutter doctor and add the screens here

Answer (score 1):

Build the app again. Try this code.

```
    Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
                           desiredAccuracy:LocationAccuracy.high);
      double lat = position.latitude;
      double long = position.longitude;
      print("Latitude: $lat and Longitude: $long");
  }
```

Comment: not worck
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: change the geolocator version to 7.6.2

Comment: did not work 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the application! should work from there onwards. Hot restart wont work when u add plugins.

Comment: no longer working

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: did u follow the instructions for android?
try flutter clean too!

Comment: update  compileSdkVersion 31   here android\app\build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs if you haven't made changes to the app as per the required app platform.

i.e, android, iOS, Web

GOTO the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) in package description under `Usage`

follow the implementation steps for the platform you are building

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you, refer `geolocator` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and `geocoding` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) for getting the *latitude* and *longitude* and your location name

Create Position and one variable for your current position and `init()` mathod

```
Position? _currentPosition;
  String? _currentAddress;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();
  }
```

Function for get Latitude and Longitude

```
 getCurrentLocation() {
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
            forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
         print(position.latitude);
         print(position.longitude);
        _getAddressFromLatLng();
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Function for location from your latitude and longitude

```
_getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude);

      Placemark place = placemarks[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress = "${place.subLocality}";//here you can used place.country and other things also
        print(_currentAddress);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
Column(
      children: [
        if (_currentPosition != null && _currentAddress != null)
          Text(
            _currentAddress!,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              letterSpacing: .5,
              fontSize: 15,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    )
```

Add below lines inside `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` file above of the `application` tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Go to `android\app\build.gradle` file and change below changes

```
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: @HamZa see my updated answer and change some code in `android\app\build.gradle` file and `re-run` your app and let me know

Answer (score 0):

There are some helpful steps to be followed by You which is mentioned on readme of package. Update

`android\app\build.gradle`

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 31

  ...
}
```