# * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run a my app in debug and I'm getting an error '*`:geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed`* ;

Here are my packages

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.1
  provider: ^5.0.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
  country_list_pick: ^1.0.1+4
  lazy_load_scrollview: 1.3.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.5+2
  image_cropper: ^1.4.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  photo_view: ^0.11.1
  pin_code_fields: ^7.1.0
  pdf: ^3.3.0
  printing: ^5.2.1
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  better_player: 0.0.73
  latlong2: ^0.8.0
  google_maps_place_picker_mb: ^2.0.0-mb.9
  flutter_html: ^2.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  flavor: ^2.0.0
  flutter_map: ^0.13.0
  extended_image: ^4.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  rich_text_controller:
  build_runner: ^2.1.1
```

And Here's my **build.gradle**.
As you can note I'm not using geolocator; could be some packages are using it.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.quodari.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

I have the Android SDK version 31 installed with Flutter 2.2.3.

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660808/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

ensure you change 'compileSdkVersion 33' from 'compileSdkVersion 31'
add 'geolocator: ^9.0.1' this to your dependencies

and when building appbundle add '--no-sound-null-safety'