# geolocator flutter not returning current location

Tags: flutter

I am using geolocator:7.7.1 on IOS simulator with flutter 2.5.1

Location service is enabled.
Permission to get location is allowed but when i try to get current location using

```
 var p = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          timeLimit: Duration(seconds: 13),
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

After 13 seconds i get the timeout exception and if i don't specify time it will just wait for ever and don't return anything. I also tried with different `LocationAccuracy`

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660808/13997210) hope its help you.

Comment: Its not different then the code i wrote. I used async/await and you have used then

Comment: Ok so you can't load your location, I think try to Change `LocationAccuracy.high` to `LocationAccuracy.best` hope it's work

Comment: I tried that too but its not working :- (

Comment: can you share your extra code for get Location