# I want to resolve geolocation errors

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of my current location using [GeoLocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator).
I read the docs.
I'm Flutter  beginner
I added key, string to info.split but the error didn't go away.
I searched but I'm in trouble because I can't find a solution.

Error message

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: User denied permissions to access the device's location.
#0      MethodChannelGeolocator.getCurrentPosition (package:geolocator_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:127:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _MyHomePageState.getLocation (package:applicationname/main.dart:37:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I added file of main.dart.
I will get data of location in this code.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _location = "no data";
 
  getLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    setState(() {
      _location = position.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_location),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              '_location',
            ),
            Text(
              '_location',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: getLocation, child: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added location permission in android manifest file?

Comment: Yes.I added code of AndroidManifest.xml in question text.

Comment: It's okay. Error is in unable to getting location. Add main.dart file if possible.

Comment: If you want get your current location refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660808/13997210)  for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _location = "no data";
 
  getLocation() async {
    final hasPermission = await _handlePermission();

    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    setState(() {
      _location = position.toString();
    });
  }
  
    Future<bool> _handlePermission() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    // Test if location services are enabled.
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      // do stuff
      return false;
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        // do stuff
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      // do stuff

      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
  getLocation();
  super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_location),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              '_location',
            ),
            Text(
              '_location',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: getLocation, child: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Successful thanks to you.Please tell me what was the cause.

Comment: Cause regarding the location permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code we cant force to send location permistion request again and again.. Use this

```
 static getLocation() async{
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

if(permission == LocationPermission.denied){
  await Geolocator.requestPermission();

  return;
}else if(permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever){
  await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();

  return;
}else{
  final position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
   print("latitude = ${position.latitude}");
   print("longitude= ${position.longitude}");
}
```

}